# MongoDB database usernames getting deleted

Tags: mongodb

Has anyone noticed a situation where the usernames to the database are deleted when all of the collections are cleared (data deleted, collections exist) using a code? I'm having a situation when I clear all the collections in a database through a C# code, all the users that had access to the database are gone and I had to recreate the users again with the passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each database in MongoDB uses [collections in the `system.*` namespace](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Metadata) for storing metadata.  For example, `system.users` for authentication and `system.indexes` for index definitions.

If you drop a database completely (eg. using `db.dropDatabase()`), the expected outcome is removal of all data for that database (including associated system collections for that database).

If you try to drop a `system` collection directly, you should get an error with "exception: can't drop system ns".